# Count number of associations with a status in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I have a model named Project and Project has many Tasks

Task can have 3 different status(integer).

I want to get a list of Projects with counts of associated Tasks in status = 1, 2 and 3.

The best i can get to is have a method on Project

```
def open_tasks
  self.tasks.where(:status => 1).count
end
```

But this will make another SQL for each count and it is very bad performance when loading 100 projects.

Is there a way to get it out in one SQL statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the counter_culture gem.

https://github.com/magnusvk/counter_culture

Answer (score 0):

I can think of a couple of ways to do this...

1. (It's not a single sql statement but two, still quite performant though)... 
   `Task.where(status: 1).group(:project_id).count`
   will give you a hash where the keys are project ids and the values are the task counts. You can then combine this with the list of projects.
2. You can use the ActiveRecord counter_cache to save in the project records a value for the number of open tasks. ActiveRecord will automatically update this for you. I believe you will need to add an association to the project model like this:

```
# app/models/project.rb
# needs to include a column called open_task_count
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :open_tasks, class_name: Task, -> { where status: 1 }
end

class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :project, counter_cache: true
end
```

Comment: #1 gives a count of all the tasks not counts per status. #2 would update a single counter cache column and also just give a total count.

Comment: did you update your question? Or perhaps I didn't read it fully. Anyway, you can get the counts of tasks per project and per status value with `Task.group(:project_id, :status).count`

Answer (score 0):

```
Project.select(
  'projects.*',
  '(SELECT COUNT(tasks.*) FROM tasks WHERE tasks.project_id = projects.id AND tasks.status = 0) AS status_0_count',
  '(SELECT COUNT(tasks.*) FROM tasks WHERE tasks.project_id = projects.id AND tasks.status = 1) AS status_1_count'
).left_joins(:tasks)
```

Although there are more elegant ways (like lateral joins and CTEs) subqueries work on most DBs. If statuses is an [ActiveRecord::Enum](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.2.3/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html) you can construct the subqueries by looping over the enum mapping:

```
class Project < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :tasks
  def self.with_task_counts
    # constucts an array of SQL strings
    statuses = Task.statuses.map do |key, int|
      sql = Task.select('COUNT(*)')
             .where('tasks.project_id = projects.id')
             .where(status: key)
             .to_sql
      "(#{sql}) AS #{key}_tasks_count"
    end
    select(
      'projects.*',
      *statuses # * turns the array into a list of args
    ).left_joins(:tasks)
  end
end
```

In Rails 4 you can still do a LEFT OUTER JOIN by using a SQL string:

```
class Project
  def self.left_joins_tasks(*args)
    deprecator = ActiveSupport::Deprecation.new("5.0", "MyApp")
    deprecator.deprecation_warning("left_joins_tasks is deprecated, use `.left_joins(:tasks)` instead")
    joins('LEFT OUTER JOIN tasks ON tasks.project_id = projects.id')
  end
end
```

Using `.joins` works as well but gives an INNER join so rows with no tasks are filtered out. You can also use `.includes`.

Comment: Forgot to say using rails 4. left_joins came in 5 i belive

Comment: @Jepzen yeah in Rails 4 you need to use .joins with a string to get the same result. https://blog.bigbinary.com/2016/03/24/support-for-left-outer-joins-in-rails-5.html

Comment: If you are on PG you can use filter instead of a subquery. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59327440/select-multiple-aggregates-of-a-joined-table-on-postgres/59327467?noredirect=1#comment104855034_59327467