# Select multiple aggregates of a joined table on Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, pivot

Given the tables `projects`:

```
 id         | bigint                         | not null default nextval('projects_id_seq'::regclass)
 name       | character varying              | 
 created_at | timestamp(6) without time zone | not null
 updated_at | timestamp(6) without time zone | not null
```

and `tasks`:

```
 id         | bigint                         | not null default nextval('tasks_id_seq'::regclass)
 name       | character varying              | 
 project_id | bigint                         | not null
 created_at | timestamp(6) without time zone | not null
 updated_at | timestamp(6) without time zone | not null
 status     | task_status                    |
```

`task_status` is an enum:

```
CREATE TYPE task_status AS ENUM ('pending', 'in_progress', 'complete')
```

I want to select name and id from projects and counts of the `pending`, `in_progress` and `complete` tasks.

```
 id |              name              | pending_tasks_count | in_progress_tasks_count | complete_tasks_count 
----+--------------------------------+---------------------+-------------------------+----------------------
  2 | Dickens, Walker and Rutherford |                   1 |                       8 |                    5
  5 | Bailey-Kreiger                 |                   0 |                       0 |                    4
  4 | Ledner, Ullrich and Davis      |                   2 |                       1 |                    2
  1 | Price-Fisher                   |                   3 |                       4 |                    1
  3 | Harber LLC                     |                   1 |                       2 |                    1
```

What I have so far is just doing three ungainly subqueries:

```
SELECT projects.id, projects.name, 
  (SELECT COUNT(tasks.*) FROM tasks WHERE tasks.project_id = projects.id 
    AND tasks.status = 'pending') AS pending_tasks_count, 
  (SELECT COUNT(tasks.*) FROM tasks WHERE tasks.project_id = projects.id 
    AND tasks.status = 'in_progress') AS in_progress_tasks_count, 
  (SELECT COUNT(tasks.*) FROM tasks WHERE tasks.project_id = projects.id 
    AND tasks.status = 'complete') AS complete_tasks_count 
FROM projects
LEFT OUTER JOIN tasks
  ON tasks.project_id = projects.id GROUP BY projects.id
```

Is there a more elegant/performant solution to select the aggregates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pivot your data with conditional aggregation. In Postgres, the `filter` functionality of aggregate functions comes handy for this:

```
select 
    p.id,
    p.name,
    count(*) filter(where t.status = 'pending') pending_tasks_count,
    count(*) filter(where t.status = 'in_progress') in_progress_tasks_count,
    count(*) filter(where t.status = 'complete') complete_tasks_count
from projects p
inner join tasks t on t.project_id = p.id
group by p.id, p.name
```

Comment: Thanks! How does PG know here that status refers to the tasks table?

Comment: @max: welcome! It knows because only the `task` table has a column named `status` (there is no such column in the `project` table). But you are right pointing this out, it is always better to be explicit about which table a column comes from, by prefixing it with the table name or alias. I modified my query accordingly.